# C++: Parameter type that requires inheritance from few interface-like classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to be able to create non-template function that requires type of class to be inherited from few another classes.

Something like that

```
class A1
{};

class A2
{};

class A3
{};

class B: public A1, public A2, public A3
{};

class C: public A1, public A3
{};

void Foo(const C&)
{}

int main(void)
{
    B b;
    C c;

    Foo(b); // error. But B inherited from A1 and A3, so I want to be able pass it
    Foo(c); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

I will glad to hear any suggestions to solve the problem.

*Note: some languages like Swift and Objective-C have this functionality as part of the language calling 'conforming protocols'*

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing what it is you want `Foo` to do such that it works with `B`.

Answer (score 2):

If you relax (eliminate) the requirement of non-templateness, it's done through SFINAE, for instance:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<A1, T>::value
        && std::is_base_of<A3, T>::value>::type
    Foo(T const &);
```

Otherwise you'll need more tricks, more specifically, you'll still need a templated solution though templates should be isolated to elsewhere. One possible solution, sketched out briefly, would be something like:

```
struct A1 {};
struct A2 {};

struct B: A1, A2 {};
struct C: A1, A2 {};

template<class B1, class B2> struct product {
    template<class T> product(T &t): b1(t), b2(t) {}
    operator B1 &() const { return b1; }
    operator B2 &() const { return b2; }
private:
    B1 &b1;
    B2 &b2;
};

void f(product<A1, A2> p) {}

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    f(b);
    f(c);
}
```

(For brevity I've limited the amount of bases to two—you can actually extend this multiview adapter to an arbitrary pack—and left aside constructing from temporaries—still not a rocket science.)

Comment: wouldnt it be T instead of C

Comment: the reason to avoid temperateness is that Foo function should be able to be virtual  (pure) function of some classes

Comment: That's quite a different problem. Would you provide more context, like type relations etc.?

Comment: Might want to add some constraints on `product`'s constructor.

Comment: @bipll Right now `std::is_constructible<product<A1, A2>, int>::value` is true.  If I construct it with an `int`, that won't compile - if that's what you mean by ad-hoc. But it'd be nice if the trait also gave the right answer.

Comment: Barry, oh sure, we'll need to define a trait (and probably few other things not shown here.)

Answer (score 1):

Define a new interface `I` that derives from both `A1` and `A3` (but doesn't implement any of its pure virtual functions), and make `Foo` take `const I&`. The classes that derive from `I` will have to override the pure virtuals in both `A1` and `A3`.

Comment: It should be more flexible: another Foo-like functions could accept any combination of required base classes.